# catch never outputs the console even though I know it's failing

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, frontend, backend

I have my mongodb service stopped, so I know that my front end is not connected to my DB. I am using react and express.

Upon my app starting, I want to indicate that to the user somehow the server is offline so I figured if my original get call for users fails, then the server is offline.

I'm doing a simple call:

```
componentDidMount () {
        axios.get ('/api/users')
        .then ((res) => this.setState(
            { users : res.data }
        ))
        .catch ((error) => {
            //console.error(error);
            console.log('error found : offline');
        }); 
    }
```

But nothing happens in situation. I never get the catch call for the console. Am I going about this wrong? I'm new to backend so this is all a learning experience for me.

I was going to set a failed flag and then render a display error for the user and then retry the connection every 1500ms or something (is that bad programming?).

Comment: Is your request shown in the browser network tab ? What response did you get ? Also, are you sure that you're code is executed ?

Comment: Open the Network tab in chrome and inspect that request. Does it fail? If not it may resopnd with something unexepected.

Comment: Under the network tab, I find the users and the status is pending. 
I'm 100% certain my application is working on the front end. It just failed after 2.5 mins.

Comment: Maybe you need to wait for the request to time out.

Comment: time out occurs generally after 60 seconds, so, your can retry every 1500ms but you'll have to cancel the last executed request.

Comment: Retrying is only a good choice if the request is likely to succeed in the future. The database being down is not exactly a common error in production. Also your backend should probably not wait for the database 60 seconds and return a response much earlier. If the problem can be resolved by the user it is better to provide a way to manually trigger a retry. But that heavily depends on the use case.

Comment: Doesnt that seem like a fairly long time though? 
This part of my application is the user login ( a pin pad). I thought it would make sense that they would attempt to punch in pin, or have a serve status light indicator to show if it's offline or online. Waiting 60 seconds to determine server status is long, is it not? Maybe I'm looking at this all wrong.